# ERROR: dotnet CLI tools are not installed!

Tags: command-line

I am really new to Ubuntu and anything related. I'm coming up against this problem

[image]

on PuTTY.

This is the script I'm trying to run

[image]

Any help?

Comment: What is the content of this script `cc.sh`? Which Ubuntu release do you have?

Comment: What do you mean content of the script. Ubuntu version is 14.04.5

Comment: You are trying to execute `cc.sh` . It's not a executable file, but a script. Please `cat cc.sh` to see what commands it intends to do.

Comment: [this](https://i.imgur.com/pbXUvaA.png) is what i got from it, i do not understand any if it since i used a tutorial on how to use the program on ubuntu.

Comment: Just talked to the dev of the program, he said i need to download _.NET Core SDK._ for it to work. I have no idea on how to download that and he doesnt help people with downloading stuff.

Comment: That's Microsoft package. There's support for Linux, according to [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core). It's recommended to follow step-by-step instructions, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up `.Net` `CLI` on Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 17.04

1. Register Microsoft trusted signature:

   - `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg`
   - `sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg`
2. Register the Microsoft Product feed for your distro version:

   - Ubuntu 17.04:

     ```
     sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-zesty-prod zesty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'`
     ```
   - Ubuntu 16.04:

     ```
     sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
     ```
   - Ubuntu 14.04:

     ```
     sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-trusty-prod trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
     ```
3. Install .NET Core SDK:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
   ```
4. How to use:

   ```
   dotnet new console -o hwapp
   cd hwapp
   ```
5. Run the app:

   ```
   dotnet run
   ```

If all goes well your `CLI` is now setup.

Source:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu